# Weekly Demand Forecasting using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have been trying to forecast the results of the following data. These are weekly numbers and I have tired ARIMA and ETS and it seems I am not getting the correct results. I have set the frequency as 365.25/7 and tried auto.arima with stepwise = FALSE and approximation = FALSE. Also tried Fourier. The results that I get are as seen below. Could anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong. How do we get the up and downs (drift) in the forecast ?

Point Forecast : 
992.2797 1057.1385 1057.4956 1082.3302 1089.3869 1100.8245 1106.7030 1112.7030 1116.6169 1119.9958 1122.4300 1124.3969

Data is as follows. The information is from 2009-01-04 till 2018-06-15. I was using data from 2018 as test set.

311
1389
1006
1407
6456
1295
2419
1643
915
926
909
1165
1041
1271
2825
1034
967
3149
2188
1128
2427
1583
1049
1225
1134
1283
3861
1298
1169
1057
1220
1296
1457
2313
1511
1649
1429
944
1225
2932
1662
1068
2056
2680
1164
1350
1595
1528
1241
977
2713
2369
864
1499
2364
1317
1068
1756
1333
1148
1340
1519
1560
1326
1325
2219
1308
1283
1657
1350
1048
1134
2372
2392
1233
1495
1251
978
4284
907
909
1268
910
999
1027
2132
2397
2289
1336
1260
973
2092
1392
1155
2465
3046
927
836
2331
2956
1626
1565
2388
1984
868
1276
1045
980
2009
3757
1032
1666
1148
2032
1386
1733
1545
1910
1322
994
1990
951
1206
952
1987
2894
1598
1039
1871
1270
2705
1744
857
1819
1249
688
1848
1432
1957
2055
1069
1831
1207
1038
1819
1119
1892
2037
1200
1724
1974
1670
1853
1071
1569
2533
723
1315
1124
1053
820
1899
1017
1603
1093
1671
1115
1224
967
1853
1684
1017
811
1811
1094
1035
794
2612
1453
912
1368
857
2371
2156
883
685
1031
813
1272
1010
1876
1875
1261
888
1756
1129
1152
1039
1718
1852
1417
1782
1634
1414
1056
1069
1643
1836
1092
998
1531
1108
1020
1822
941
1081
1029
1495
981
1175
1648
1410
1186
866
1394
1253
867
732
1261
2273
1190
765
2220
1390
1384
1484
676
993
1135
830
848
810
2240
1494
856
686
1548
1018
779
1751
1593
886
685
836
841
1448
1084
755
1941
1921
1039
1093
829
1237
935
1305
824
1120
931
766
1463
1354
791
1062
803
779
1335
802
730
1177
1101
1255
1098
735
1609
1049
1109
1041
723
690
1000
1477
1034
1041
1176
1066
669
778
765
790
1436
1069
731
732
721
790
842
1203
1078
717
890
655
718
782
1265
855
1164
1173
735
1066
826
948
797
1188
816
1005
1131
736
566
1056
879
1198
1132
1253
1064
915
1351
1352
1184
1700
1005
937
1013
1322
1052
966
1356
1178
1985
1422
1051
1045
1537
1633
1543
1468
1251
1761
1483
2213
1794
2245
1170
1872
1737
1098
1283
1344
1388
1256
2408
1692
1789
2379
1209
1448
1167
2194
1480
1168
1023
1512
1333
1297
1501
1311
2672
1591
1319
1918
2003
2254
1513
1419
1675
1812
1230
1153
1500
1222
2288
1223
973
968
1058
1473
1372
1010
1257
1219
1081
2356
1645
1059
931
1973
1741
987
755
877
1210
997
1802
936
696
956
738
644
994
766
902
902
2061
925
759
752
969
793
1883
992
699
1704
813
1440
1044
902
1301
1594
959
622
1339
1092
1335
925
848
663
669
1061
1452
794
1430
884
760
1610
1226
860
806
1449
1755
1066
689
722
674
702
1499
793
613
632
618
625
649
1471
1735
811
662
718
763
1594
1353
1404
1865
953
605
983

Comment: Why do you believe you are doing something wrong?

Comment: There are spikes up and down while plotting the time series. but I do not get those while doing the forecast. I am confused on whether I am missing some parameters.

Comment: What ARIMA parameters are you using? (FWIW, predicting weeks is messy: first they don't line up from year to year, second there are moving holidays, etc.)

Comment: I did try Dynamic Harmonic regression. "Forecast from Regression with ARIMA(5,1,5) errors"

Comment: @Wayne which is precisely why we recommend daily data to our clients.

Comment: @IrishStat  - Based on the above replies, when you consider daily data would you set the frequency as 365 or 366 ? How would you handle leap year ? Or is that you will set a weekly frequency (7) ?

Comment: Please see my answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354726/count-data-time-series-for-hospital-emergency-arrivals/354889#354889 as it suggests creating a hybrid model using both dummies and arima. This is what I did  with your data. I will expand my answer .

Answer (score 1):

A time series is composed of signal and noise. A forecasting method attempts to extract and extrapolate the signal, and discard the noise. (By definition, noise is random and unforecastable, so trying to forecast the noise will make the forecast worse.)

The spikes you see may be systematic, as in AR or MA dynamics, in which case they will be modeled and forecasted. Or, more likely, they are noise, in which case they will not be forecasted, and this is correct.

A forecast is always smoother than the original series, because the noise has been removed.

As to where the ups and downs come from: most likely from seasonal or ARIMA behavior your model has detected. If I fit a straightforward `forecast::auto.arima()` to your data (which is inappropriate, given the seasonality), I get an ARIMA(1,1,3) model, which does exhibit some dynamics.

ARIMA models are not very happy about "long" seasonal cycles. You may want to look at [bats](/questions/tagged/bats) or [tbats](/questions/tagged/tbats) models. Then again, if you have already included Fourier terms, these models will likely not improve matters dramatically.

You may want to look at some material on forecasting, e.g., [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice*](https://otexts.org/fpp2/). Or at [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352)

Answer (score -1):

By including a time trend indicator , level shifts , some pulses , significant weekly indicators and a (1,0,0) arima structure .... this is the actual, fit and forecasts [image]   suggesting the patterns in the past are replicated/projected into the future. No boring forecasts here !

The model is here [image] and here [image] and here [image] yielding forecasts here [image]

The residuals from the model suggest sufficiency [image]

In short analysts are often limited by their (free) tools thus you get people promoting simple memory models ...even when they are inappropriate.

Your weekly series has complications (opportunities) as changes in trend and changes in level have been detected. When you have  a leap year weekly indicators often need to be modified thus the "changes in seasonal(dummy) factors".